# Bash script in background with control posibility

Tags: bash, function, sockets, background, subshell

I want to create the script which runs function in background, but leaves ability to query that function about results, pause, resume or other way to interact with it.

For simplicity, lets say, i want to run the counter in the background which increases each second. For user interaction i will leave endless loop with read function.

When I enter `p` I expect to see current `$counter` value.

When I enter `q` I expect `while` loop in `loop_counter` function will stop as I set `$RUN` to `false`.

```
#!/bin/bash
RUN=true
counter=0

print_counter() {
        echo "Current value is: $counter"
}

loop_counter() {
        while $RUN
        do
                echo $counter >> file
                ((counter++))
                sleep 1
        done
}

loop_counter &

while true
do
        echo "Print or Quit?"
        read x

        case $x in
                p) print_counter ;;
                q) RUN=false; break ;;
                *) echo "Use p or q!" ;;
        esac
done

wait
```

I print `$counter` value to `file`, just to watch on another terminal with `tail -f file`

When I hit `p` I get `0` as `$counter` loops in subshell.

When I hit `q` script brakes from the `while` loop and it `wait`s for subprocess in background will stop. Unfortunately it continues as variable `$RUN` in function `loop_counter` remains `true`.

Any ideas how can I read the current value of `$counter` or change the value of `$RUN`? Is it possible to create something like a socket?

Thanks

Comment: `loop_counter &` kicks off a separate, asynchronous process that is no longer associated with your current script, so something like a call to `print_counter` is going to print the counter for the current process which is ... 0; to enable communications between the 2 processes you could look at a) some sort of socket solution, b) using a combo of `kill` and signals (`loop_counter` would need to `trap` said signals and take the appropriate action), c) passing directives (and data?) via a FIFO/pipe and/or file ...

Comment: ... a variation on the 'pipe' idea would be coprocesses whereby the stdin and/or stdout of the processes is redirected to pipes, and then messages can be passed via said pipes

Comment: I don't think there's a great direct way to do this, but you can do amazing things with Redis (`redis-cli`) if you want to stick with bash.

Comment: You can export   `RUN` and `counter` variables, so they will be accessible by parent script,

Comment: @markp-fuso. Yes, trap works well if one action is need all the time. But if multiple different actions is needed - this will not work. I thought to use socat UNIX-LISTEN:mysocket,fork EXEC:print_counter and trigger it with socat UNIX:mysocket - <<<"p", but socat cant execute functions. Just script. And still, we need to run socat to background and let the script work further, which means it will start new isolated subshell. Trying to figure it out how to use synergy of socat, trap and/or netcat to achieve this...